# Neat-python FeedForwordNetwork.activate takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given even though config file shows 6

Tags: python, neat

When I ran my neat code I got this error in FeedForwardNetwork.activate() :

```py
output = nets[x - 2].activate(player_.red_x, player_.red_y, player_.blue_x, player_.blue_y, player_.catcher,
TypeError: FeedForwardNetwork.activate() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I am unable to load imgs as I don't have enough reputation, but here is an image link: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osLvE.jpg)

This is what I did to load the file

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put the items in a list.

```py
output = nets[x - 2].activate([player_.red_x, player_.red_y, player_.blue_x, player_.blue_y, player_.catcher,last_parm])
```